# React Auth0-JS - Console error 'Unepected token <'

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I'm getting the following error in the console for my react app after installing auth0-js, despite having not touched any of the files for the module:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

at auth0.js:1

Seems to be affecting other things, because a request to my api using postman is returning this when I try to view the json response.

Comment: I'm getting this error too. Did you ever find a solution?